# Updating genuine repositories fails in Trusty Tahr

Tags: 14.04, apt

I was installing Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS x64 in a virtual box running on Windows 8 x64. On running installer I haven't entered anything into dialog asking for some required proxy setup. The VM is attached to the web using bridged networking by default.

This VM is used for testing some inhouse development of an installer script. Thus I've taken a snapshot after basic installer has been finished. I can properly boot that VM and always revert to that snapshot for retrying our own installer.

Those tests are always starting this way:

1. revert VM to initial snapshot
2. clone installer from remotely hosted SVN using `git svn` (always succeeding)
3. invoke cloned installer

That installer is used to invoke

```
apt-get update
```

on first launch and again once a day on repeated invocations. In addition it is invoking

```
apt-get upgrade
```

once a day and uses

```
apt-get install <somepackage>
```

for installing required but missing dependencies.

- **The installer isn't adding any PPA currently.**
- The snapshot isn't listing any PPAs either.

However, even in a VM freshly reverted to that snapshot the installer's initial invocation of `apt-get update` occasionally fails due to not finding some repositories or having mismatching Hash sums on selected repositories.

Due to this issue we currently can't advise our customers to upgrade existing installations to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS though it's including several highly beneficial improvements (e.g. in supporting LXC).

A currently proven solution is

1. waiting 30-60 minutes
2. reverting VM to initial snapshot again
3. relaunching installer checking if updating repos succeeds or not

I'm quite sure this isn't related to our office's web connectivity for it is occurring in different places, at different times and days, while streaming from the web, skyping with audio/video etc. without any problems.

Here is my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
#

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.3)]/ trusty main restricted

#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.3)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

There aren't any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` ...

Comment: When you revert the VM are you re-starting the network to re-initialise DHCP leases, bring up the virtual ethernet etc? Do you get the errors on systems running on real hardware, or is it just VM? Do you get the errors if you run the VM continuously, or only when you revert state? Have you run `wireshark` or `tcpdump` to see what is actually happening between the client and server?

Comment: Whenever issue was encountered it was reproducible while keeping VM running. I don't restart the whole network. It's just that single VM to be reverted. In addition it isn't affecting all but some provider sites updated lists are fetched from per run of `apt-get update`. So network is available. Currently all my dedicated servers are kept running on Precise, but I'm quite sure also having seen similar issues on a minor server I was upgrading from Precise to Trusty previously. There aren't any PPAs in use either, though this is a whole different story for sure (due to dist-upgrading).

Comment: To my regrets I was missing to take snapshots of logfiles or similar. I'll attach those when observing this case again. BTW: haven't used `tcpdump`, will give it a try then.